# C++/CLI Syntax Clarification

Tags: c++-cli

In looking into marshal_as one of the function calls expects the following format:

```
System::String^ const &
```

What is the purpose of the `const &` after the managed pointer?

This does not compile for me:

```
static std::wstring GetString(const System::String^ value)
{
    return msclr::interop::marshal_as<std::wstring>(value);
}
```

Error   1   error C4996:

'msclr::interop::error_reporting_helper<_To_Type,_From_Type>::marshal_as': This conversion is not supported by the library or the header file needed for this conversion is not included.  Please refer to the documentation on 'How to: Extend the Marshaling Library' for adding your own marshaling method.  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\msclr\marshal.h   203

This does:

```
static std::wstring GetString(const System::String^ value)
{
    return msclr::interop::marshal_as<std::wstring>(const_cast<System::String^>(value));
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The marshal_as method is defined by this template:

```
template <class _To_Type, class _From_Type>
inline _To_Type marshal_as(const _From_Type&);
```

The primary purpose of the extra `const &` is to conform to this template declaration.

This does affect how the function is called: I checked the IL, and the `String^` is passed as a const indirect reference, as one would expect, but that's not a major change.

If the method were standalone, it would probably be declared without the `const &`, and there would be little difference.

---

You're trying to call a method `String^ const &` with a `String^ const`. The compiler can't make that conversion automatically (safely).

What you're doing with your const_cast is turning the `String^ const` into a regular `String^`. The compiler *can* turn `String^` into `String^ const &` safely and automatically.

I'd just remove the `const` from your local method declaration. This compiles for me:

```
static std::wstring GetString(System::String^ value)
{
    return msclr::interop::marshal_as<std::wstring>(value);
}
```

Why can't the compiler make that conversion? Note that `String^ const &` and `const String^ const &` are not the same thing. The first one says "A constant pointer to a string object". The second says "A constant pointer to a *constant string object*". In your method with `(const System::String^ value)`, you've got a constant string object, and the function you're calling expects a pointer to a non-const string object. We know that the String class is immutable, but the compiler doesn't, so it won't pass the address to a const object to a method that thinks the object is non-const.

(I'm using Visual Studio 2010 SP1, but I don't believe the marshal methods had any major changes between 2008 and 2010.)

Comment: I only ask, because I had a function that I wrote to take a const System::String^ and convert it to a std::wstring and the function prototype didn't like it without a const_cast<System::String^>.

Comment: Can you show more code regarding the const_cast? I was unable to re-create that error: I tried declaring a method as taking `const String^` and I can call it without using const_cast.

Comment: I've modified the original question to include the non-working and the working example.  I'm using Visual Studio 2008 SP1 if it matters.

Comment: I'd just remove the `const` from your local method declaration. The String class is immutable, it doesn't need `const` protection. See edit.

Comment: Ah.. gotcha.  I breaks all of the call sights where I use my helper method though.  Blah. :)